# Line break glitch with code tag

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, formatting

Line breaks with `code` involved leave a thin piece of the `code` formatting in the previous line:

[image]

This only seems to happen with the Opera browser (ver. 11.00/11.01).

Comment: One could argue that that makes it an Opera bug rather than an askubuntu bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is an Opera bug, not a bug in our HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

For now I work around this by overriding the `code` tag padding using a user style sheet for askubuntu.com:

```
p code {
  padding: 1px 3px!important;
}
```